# How to prevent QPushButton call signal two times?

Tags: c++, qt

The situation is:
In the "create course", I click "Save1" Button (time 1 , and it call setUpStep2Action()), It goes to step 2 and disable "Save1" button ... After saving all info, I add more course, so "Save1" Button is enable. And when i click "Save1" Button (time 2), it call setUpStep2Action() 2 times. 
I dont know what happen and how to prevent this issue.
Thanks.

void step2SaveAction(int courseId) 
{

```
  int numElement = ui.rightWidget->count();
  if(numElement == 0)
  {
    QMessageBox::warning(this,tr("Skill choice"),tr("Please choose skills!!"));
    return;
  }

  char* method = "CREATE";
 if ( courseId !=0)
    method = "EDIT";

 setup4Step3(method,courseId,numElement );
 ui.addMoreButton->setVisible(true);
```

}

I put the connect in the constructor. Here is my code where connect is created:

```
    QSignalMapper *signalMapper1 = new QSignalMapper(this);
    signalMapper1->setMapping(ui.courseNameLineEdit,0);
    QObject::connect(ui.courseNameLineEdit,SIGNAL(returnPressed()),signalMapper1, SLOT(map()));
    QObject::connect(signalMapper1, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this, SLOT(step1SaveAction(int)));
```

Comment: You've likely connected the `clicked()` signal to the `setUpStep2Action()` slot multiple times, but it's impossible to tell unless you post your code.

Comment: post how u done connect() function ..

Comment: Yes. I did upload the code :) Thanks

Comment: But the point is not in my code. It may be in the way QPushButton work. Because, for the 1st time I do "Add Course", everything run well. For the 2nd time I "Add course", the signal (step2SaveAction) run 2 times, and if I try one more "add course", the signal run 3 times.

Comment: No, believe me and the others, the issue is not in the way QPushButton works ;-) You haven't provided the code where `connect` is, which is what would help us to tell you what's wrong. :)

Comment: I did it. :) THanks. Is that the suitable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much agree with all comments here, that you add a new connection each time you click your button. You say you don't. Easy to test. There is a nice, rarely used option for connections: Qt::UniqueConnection.

Change your connections to:

```
bool success = false;
success = QObject::connect(ui.courseNameLineEdit,SIGNAL(returnPressed()),
signalMapper1, SLOT(map()),Qt::UniqueConnection);
if(!success){
  qFatal() << "Connection failed1";
}
sucess = QObject::connect(signalMapper1, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this, 
SLOT(step1SaveAction(int)),Qt::UniqueConnection);
if(!success){
  qFatal() << "Connection failed2";
}
```

If you are right and your program continues to run, we have to brainstorm more. :-)

Btw... didn't you tell us something about a button? You connects connect a LineEdit. But nevertheless, do above thing with all your connections.

Comment: Thanks much. Everytime, I clicked "Add more", a new lineEdit with it connection is created. You're right. I create 2 connections for it. The option "Qt::UniqueConnection" seems not working well. But I know how to deal with it now. :)

Comment: @ndnguyen `Qt::UniqueConnection` is working exactly how we want it to: informing us there is already a identical connection

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comment from RA, you probably connected the `clicked()` signal to the `setUpStep2Action()` slot multiple times. I suppose that this occurs because when you add a course, you do something like:

```
void addCourse()
{
    // ...
    save1Button->setEnabled(true);
    connect(save1Button, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this,        SLOT(setUpStep2Action()));
}
```

Hence one more connection is added each time you add a course. What you have to do instead is to call `connect` only once, in the constructor of the class that contains the button, for instance.

Then simplify your `addCourse()` method with only this:

```
void addCourse()
{
    // ...
    save1Button->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: I make the connect outside the signal function( in the constructor). And I don't call the connect inside the signal function one more time. :(

Answer (score 0):

pass last parameter in your connection as `Qt::UniqueConnection.`

like

QObject::connect(ui.courseNameLineEdit,SIGNAL(returnPressed()),signalMapper1, SLOT(map()),Qt::UniqueConnection);